# display arabic numbers in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, localization

I use VS2010,C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, I want to display my numbers in Arabic/Farsi mode, I mean both markup numbers and numbers displayed through code, what are my options? I've used lang="ar", dir="rtl" but nothing changes, should my users change anything in their browsers? I've seen several sites that display Arabic numbers but I've not changed my browser settings at all!
should I convert anything in my code? what about markup pages?

thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298153/how-can-i-convert-english-digits-to-arabic-digits

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055195/string-format-not-converting-integers-correctly-in-arabic

Comment: thanks Heinzi, I just copied Arabic numbers instead of English numbers in my markup ASPX file, it is working fine, now I should convert something in my CS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of this is related to users system configurations.
EX: in windows vista, server 2008
control panel => region and language settings => additional settings => numbers tab => check standard digits and use native digits options

however you should be doing the following in your code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar-EG");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar-EG");
```

Comment: does this code work for all systems? I should use it in all of code behinds?

Comment: in Every Page InitializeCulture event

Comment: alternatively you can add this to web.config in
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
<system.web>

Comment: I put this codes in my page load, but I do not have Arabic numbers, what is going wrong?

Comment: you don't put in load event. You have to put it on InitializeCulture event  
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
} and also you will have to change digit format as I mentioned