# Decode text into Arabic and English

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to decode the encoded text stored in a database, which will give some Arabic characters along with a few English words and displaying them on the web page (.aspx), but its showing junk characters although English words are coming perfect.

Now I am using the below code:-

```
byte[] plain = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
lblmsg.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plain);
```

Please help me out with some solution.

Test: I pasted the encoded part over the web to decode it and it's giving the correct text(Arabic and English), but I'm not able to do it programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try using encoding in your page on which you are displaying the Arabic characters

```
<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: no its not working, suppose i just wanted to display in plane label of windows form.

Comment: @Ars http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298153/how-can-i-convert-english-digits-to-arabic-digits