# How to read each character in string and replace with urdu characters

Tags: c#, string

> This is a different approach to a completely different question, it's
>   not arabic it's urdu.  it's not date time it's string.

I want to read each character in a string and replace it with urdu characters.

For example:

```
string amount = "100";
```

I want to read each string.

> if its 1 it should replace it with urdu character ١
>    if its 0 it should replace it with urdu character ٠

and end result will be of ١٠٠

how can I break this down, I tried using this:

```
var output = "";
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if (c == 1) 
    { 
        output = "١";      
    }

    output += c;
}
```

I also want to concatenate characters.

Comment: What is the problem with this implementation? or you are just asking a better way to do it?

Comment: Use chained `.Replace("old","new")` since you only have 10 digits.

Comment: this is not working, it's not converting 1 into ١

Comment: `var output = str.Replace("1", "١").Replace("0", "٠");`  One of the problems with your current code is `output = "١";` is overwriting, not concatenating.

Comment: since `c` is a char then your condition should be `c == '1'`

Comment: Jonesopolis, its working

Comment: what this line: `if (c == 1)` does is compare whether the UTF-16 Code of the char is equal to 1. Take a look at @FirstStep answer

Comment: yes... hes correct it should be if (c == '1').

Comment: @Jonesopolis method is very very easy!. Yes that's over-writing, thanks for pointing out mistakes guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `Dictionary<char, char>` for substitutions; `string.Concat` for concatenation:

```
 Dictionary<char, char> urdu = new Dictionary<char, char>() {
   {'0', '١'},
   {'1', '٠'},
   //TODO: add other pairs here
 };

 ...

 string source = "100";

 char u;

 string result = string.Concat(source.Select(c => urdu.TryGetValue(c, out u) ? u : c));
```

Comment: I feel this one is quiet easy, what do you think? `var output = str.Replace("1", "١").Replace("0", "٠");`

Comment: @Patrick: it's easy if you have *two characters only* to substitute. What it you have to substitute `'0'..'9'` (*ten*) and `A`..`Z` as a possibility?

Comment: if i substitute 0-9 characters then writing 1500 will give me ١٥٠٠. or writing any 9831238 will give me these characters ٩٨٣١٢٣٨, so simple, thanks for answering tho.

Comment: this approach also works, since there is no correct answer other than this and one in comments given by @jonesopolis, il select this as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `c` is a char then your condition should be `if(c == '1')` <- the `char` one and not the `int` one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing code every time this functionality I would prefer extension method with repeated replace called to input string, like it is done at [How can i convert english digits to arabic digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298153/how-can-i-convert-english-digits-to-arabic-digits)

Comment: I want to convert date time to urdu date time characters as well, but this is for another stackoverflow question, if i couldn't find this out.

Comment: Use can use DateTime.Now.ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));

Comment: this writes in arabic, do you know for urdu.

Comment: This maybe of some help http://timtrott.co.uk/culture-codes/