# Handle request body with Arabic datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET core API with Model like below

```
public class UserDetails
 {
    public string name{ get; set; };
    public DateTime SyncTime{ get; set; };
 }
```

sometimes i got a request body with `SyncTime` in Arabic digits like **٢٠١٧-١١-٠٥ ٠٩:٠٨:٠١** 
is there any way to handle this kind of format and process request correctly?

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298153/how-can-i-convert-english-digits-to-arabic-digits, in first answer, there is a convert method. just do it inverse. .Replace('\u06f1','1') instead of Replace('1', '\u06f1') and etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the choice, it's usually easiest to dictate that the client sends all `DateTime` objects as either unix milliseconds, or as a `DateTime` using the standard `"O"` [round-trip format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip). Since you are writing the API, you are the one that determines what is valid input, and can reject anything not in this format.

I understand that you don't always have that luxury, in which case you can write a custom model binder for `DateTime`, which uses a specific culture:

```
public class ArabicDateTimeBinder: IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelName = bindingContext.BinderModelName;
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        DateTime dateTime;
        // I'm unsure whether this will handle the arabic digits correctly or not, so I have also included the suggested approach by g.Irani as a fallback
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value, new CultureInfo("ar"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelResult.Success(dateTime);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // As per g.Irani's suggestion:
        value = value.Replace('\u06f0', '0')
                .Replace('\u06f1', '1')
                .Replace('\u06f2', '2')
                .Replace('\u06f3', '3')
                .Replace('\u06f4', '4')
                .Replace('\u06f5', '5')
                .Replace('\u06f6', '6')
                .Replace('\u06f7', '7')
                .Replace('\u06f8', '8')
                .Replace('\u06f9', '9');

        if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateTime))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelResult.Success(dateTime);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "DateTime was not in the expected format");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell ASP.Net to use this binder. You can do this either with an annotation directly on the class, which is the simplest method:

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public string name{ get; set; };
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ArabicDateTimeBinder))]
    public DateTime SyncTime{ get; set; };
}
```

Or, you can create and register an `IModelBinderProvider`. When you register this provider, it will apply to *all* models that include a `DateTime` member. For more information on custom model binders, [have a look at the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding).

```
public class ArabicDateTimeBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(DateTime))
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(ArabicDateTimeBinder));

        return null;
    }
}
```

Register the provider in your `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // All your other service configuration stuff
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        // add custom binder to beginning of collection
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ArabicDateTimeBinderProvider());
    });
}
```

*Disclaimer: I have not run the above code, I'm just writing from what I can remember. It should work but there may be one or two things you need to fix up.*

Answer (score -1):

```
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("ar");
        string datepattern = culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
        DateTimeFormatInfo datetimeFormatInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
        datetimeFormatInfo.LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        culture.DateTimeFormat = datetimeFormatInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        DateTime dateArabic = DateTime.Now; //SyncTime
        //---
        DateTime SyncTime;
        if(DateTime.TryParse(" ٢٠١٧-١١-٠٥ ٠٩:٠٨:٠١ ", new CultureInfo("ar")) == null){//Error};
```

Comment: This solution would require the OP to change the model, so that `SyncTime` is a string, not a DateTime. Then the parsing logic would need to be executed explicitly by any controller method that wanted to access `SyncTime` as a DateTime. Also, `DateTime.TryParse` is supposed to take the output destination (SyncTime) as an `out` parameter, and it returns a boolean indicating success or failure, not null.